# Redondear imagen

Tags: php, laravel

Hola a todos necesito ayuda ya que estoy haciendo una pagina web con laravel en la que eliges tu foto de perfil, el problema es que la foto de perfil la demuestra de forma ovalada, he intentado de algunas formas que se demuestre de forma completamente redonda pero no lo he conseguido, esto es algo como lo que he intentado por si el problema era el tamaño de la imagen usando [esta libreria](http://image.intervention.io), este es el código php:

```
  $img = Image::make(File::get($image_path));

  $img->resize(100, 100);
  $img->save(Storage::disk('users')->put($image_path_full, File::get($image_path)));
```

La variable `$image_path` es la imagen que me llega por el formulario y `$image_path_full` es una variable con la que hago que el nombre de la imagen sea único, este es el codigo css que he intentado (no soy bueno en css por lo que no se si los estilos esten del todo bien):

```
.navbar .container-avatar
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.navbar .container-avatar .avatar
{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

La clase `navbar` es la barra de navegación y `container-avatar` es la caja de la imagen y finalmente la clase `avatar` es la imagen.

Y este es el resultado que me da incluyendo la imagen que muestro en el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo este es el código completo de mi formulario de la imagen:

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" required>
```

Agradezco su ayuda :).

Comment: La imagen se muestra ovalada por tu css... le estás dando un ancho de 50px y un alto de 30px. Para que se muestre redonda, dale a ambos el mismo valor, o ambos 30px o ambos 50px.

Comment: Ya lo intente dándole a ambos el mismo como dices y sigue igual, ya actualice la pregunta de como lo deje

Comment: @Davidflogar pon también el código del form por favor.

Comment: <img src="..." alt="..." class="rounded-circle"> si estas usando bootstraps esta clase te puede ayudar

Comment: @HeynerMartinez intente con esa clase pero la imagen termina usando mas especio del que le indique

Comment: @JosueArriola ya actualice la pregunta con el formulario

Comment: @Davidflogar quítale el `width: 100%;`. La estás estirando, sin contar que el css que pones es solo el del navbar y no se para qué agregas el código de un `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te han dicho varios, creo que el problema está en el CSS, puedes solventarlo fácilmente haciendo una clase en CSS, por ejemplo, `img-avatar`, ahi añades `border-radius: 50%;` y usar esa clase para hacer la imagen redonda, algo así:

```css
.img-avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Imagen con la clase</h3>
<img class = "img-avatar" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png">
<h3>Imagen sin la clase</h3>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: Gracias, de la manera en la que mencionas ya logro quedar de forma redonda, un ultimó problema es que la imagen pierde un poco de calidad, ¿hay alguna forma de evitar eso o no? si no de todos modos gracias :)

Comment: @Davidflogar mencionaste que usas una librería para redimensionar la imagen, ¿has intentado no usar la librería y cambiar el tamaño con CSS?

Comment: Ya lo intente sin usar la librería y es el mismo resultado